# Cinnamon and AMD Radeon Pro WX4130

Tags: cinnamon, amd-graphics

Here is the setup I need (or would like) in a Linux laptop:

1. A graphics card that supports OpenGL 4.5
2. Cinnamon desktop environment

Dell just came out with a line of "Systems Developed by and for Developers".  So I got the Precision 7520 with an AMD Radeon Pro WX4130 graphics card which comes pre-installed with Ubuntu 16.04 (the other option is an nVidia Quadro M1200).  I then installed Linux Mint 18.2 and after installing the AMD FirePro W4100 driver (that's the closest one I could find) http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/workstation/firepro-3d/wx4100 Cinnamon crashes.  I then upgraded Mint to the latest kernel but no luck.  So then I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 and installed Cinnamon on it.  After installing FirePro drivers Cinnamon crashes.

I'm not sure, but I feel like I've had similar issues with AMD drivers and Cinnamon in the past.  I had one laptop, a System76, which came with an nVidia GTX 1060 card and everything worked.  Also, my desktop also has an nVidia card and Cinnamon runs fine.  Is there an issue between Cinnamon and AMD drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similar ATI card with Cinnamon on Mint 18.2 **without problems.** I am using the open-source drivers with "4.10.0-32-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu" kernel.
Btw, in Mint you have the option for finding the drivers using their own tool (called "driver manager"), so please (re-)try with that?
Also, there are a lot of PPAs that hold newer drivers pre-packaged for Ubuntu (and hence can be used for Linux Mint), so you should look that up as well.